# "Standard" for in XSLT1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a template with a parameter. How can I print something n times?

n is the value of the parameter. I must use XSLT 1.0...

There's a cleaner way insted of this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;= $count]">&#x9;</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each...` ? Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can repeat an action X times with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802235/how-i-can-repeat-an-action-x-times-with-xslt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work if your source XML has `$count` elements, but I wouldn't say that's a very good way to go about it.  This is a lot more verbose, but I'd suggest defining a template like this:

```
 <xsl:template name="RepeatValue">
    <xsl:param name="times" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />

    <xsl:if test="$times > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        <xsl:call-template name="RepeatValue">
           <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$times - 1" />
           <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you would call this template using:

```
<xsl:call-template name="RepeatValue">
   <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$count" />
   <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'&#x9;'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```